Nodejs - Proxy to hit external url
I need to have an internal route that forwards a request to an external url. For this I try to use http-proxy-middleware, but I always get the message "Error occurred while trying to proxy: 127.0.0.1:8080/api/auth/token". The url I am trying to reach is something like https://${config.domain}.auth.${config.region}.com/token
What I tried to do is:
In my controller:
  public async auth(
    @Req() request: Req,
    @Res() response: Res,
  ) {
    return await this.proxyService.proxy(request, response);
  }

And in my ProxyService:
public constructor() {
    const baseUrl = `https://${config.domain}.auth.${config.region}.com`;

    const proxyOptions = {
      target: baseUrl,
      changeOrigin: true,
      on: {
        proxyReq: this.onProxyReq,
        proxyRes: this.onProxyRes,
      },
      agent: new https.Agent({ keepAlive: true }),
    };

    this.proxyMiddleware = createProxyMiddleware(proxyOptions);
  }

  public async proxy(
    request: Req,
    response: Res,
    proxyOptions: ProxyOptions = { dropBody: false }
  ): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      if (proxyOptions.dropBody) {
        request.headers['content-length'] = '0';
        delete request.headers['content-type'];
      }

      this.proxyMiddleware(request, response, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          response.status(500).json({
            statusCode: 500,
            statusDescription: err.message,
          });
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve();
        }
      });
    });
  }

The content type of the request iss x-www-form-url-encoded.
Any help?
